# Implementing Doctrine type which persists new entities with Symfony 2.8

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, entity

I have two entities **Tag** and **User**. **Tag** can be assigned to one of four categories: *sport*, *food*, *music*, *movie*. **User** has also four properties: *sport*, *food*, *music*, *movie* and each of them is array of **Tags** related with category (**user.sport** can contains tags from category *sport* and so on).

Let's see a little bit of code to be more clear.

**AcmeBundle/Entity/Tag.php**

```
namespace AcmeBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="tag")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AcmeBundle\Repository\TagRepository")
 */
class Tag
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     * 
     * @ORM\Column(name="category", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $category;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="label", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $label;
}
```

**AcmeBundle/Entity/User.php**

```
namespace AcmeBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use FOS\UserBundle\Model\User as BaseUser;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="user")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AcmeBundle\Repository\UserRepository")
 */
class User extends BaseUser
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @var Tag[]
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="sport", type="???")
     */
    private $sport;

    /**
     * @var Tag[]
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="food", type="???")
     */
    private $food;

    /**
     * @var Tag[]
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="music", type="???")
     */
    private $music;

    /**
     * @var Tag[]
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="movie", type="???")
     */
    private $movie;
}
```

Tags should be stored in the database in this form (array imploded with comma as separator).

```
user_id | sport_tags | food_tags | music_tags | movie_tags
1       | 10,21,23   | 1,2,3     | 4,5        | 100
```

I would like to persist tags automatically during persisting user. Please see below example.

```
$manager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

$user = $manager->getRepository('AcmeBundle:User')->find(1);

$tag1 = $manager->getRepository('AcmeBundle:Tag')->find(10);
$tag2 = $manager->getRepository('AcmeBundle:Tag')->find(21);
$tag3 = $manager->getRepository('AcmeBundle:Tag')->find(23);

$tag4 = new Tag();
$tag4->setLabel('New tag');
$tag4->setCategory('sport');

$user->setSport(array(
    $tag1,
    $tag2,
    $tag3,
    $tag4,
));

$manager->persist($contact);
$manager->flush();
```

After fetching user from database, id's of tags should be automatically translated to tags. Dump from below example should return array of Tags.

```
$manager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$user = $manager->getRepository('AcmeBundle:User')->find(1);
var_dump($user->getSport());
```

But I'm not sure how to implement this. I implemented new Doctrine type which converts array of tags to string (eg. "10,21,23") and vice versa. But how to automatically persist new tag? If I'm trying to persist tag in convertToDatabaseValue then it not works (server shutdown). Please see my TagType implementation below.

```
namespace AcmeBundle\Types;

use Doctrine\DBAL\Platforms\AbstractPlatform;
use Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Type;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
use AcmeBundle\Entity\Tag;

class TagType extends Type
{
    /**
     * @var EntityManager
     */
    private $manager;

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'TagType';
    }

    /**
     * @param EntityManager $manager
     */
    public function setEntityManager(EntityManager $manager)
    {
        $this->manager = $manager;
    }

    /**
     * @param array $fieldDeclaration
     * @param AbstractPlatform $platform
     * @return string
     */
    public function getSQLDeclaration(array $fieldDeclaration, AbstractPlatform $platform)
    {
        if ($fieldDeclaration['notnull']) {
            return 'LONGTEXT NOT NULL';
        } else {
            return 'LONGTEXT';
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $value
     * @param AbstractPlatform $platform
     * @return array
     */
    public function convertToPHPValue($value, AbstractPlatform $platform)
    {
        if ($value === null) {
            return array();
        } else {
            return array_filter(array_map(function ($id) {
                return $this->manager->getRepository('AcmeBundle:Tag')->find($id);
            }, explode(',', $value)));
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $value
     * @param AbstractPlatform $platform
     * @return string
     */
    public function convertToDatabaseValue($value, AbstractPlatform $platform)
    {
        if ($value === null) {
            return '';
        } else {
            return implode(',', array_filter(array_map(function (Tag $tag) {
                try {
                    return $tag->getId();
                } catch (\Exception $exception) {
                    return null;
                }
            }, $value)));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you are on the good way of doing it.
When you say `then it not works (server shutdown)` What is the actual error?